# Vertical sum using java stream api

Tags: java, java-stream

Imagine that I have a matrix of integer elements `List<List<BigDecimal>>`:

```
-------------
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
-------------
| 2 | 3 | 4 |
-------------
| 3 | 4 | 5 |
-------------
| 4 | 5 | 6 |
-------------
```

I want to vertically sum the elements of a matrix and get a `List<BigDecimal>` 
`[10, 14, 18]`

I suppose first I have to transpose the matrix and then it's easy to get the sum of the elements. But how to perfectly transpose a matrix using stream api??

Comment: Please share your **attempt** to address the problem and specify the issues you've encountered.

Answer (score 2):

One way to transform the 2D list is to map to an object and by collecting that list we can find the transpose of the 2D list as below:

```
List<List<BigDecimal>> result = IntStream.range(0, list.get(0).size())
                        .mapToObj(i -> list.stream().map(l -> l.get(i)).collect(Collectors.toList()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And Without transposing, you can directly find the sum of the list using reduce function below:

```
List<BigDecimal> result = IntStream.range(0, list.get(0).size())
                        .mapToObj(i -> list.stream().map(l -> l.get(i)).reduce(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Nice answer. May be worth to mention that this only works if the sublist sizes are equal like given in the example.

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER: This isn't the efficient way with streams or something fancy that you could do in just a couple lines, but it is a simple easy-to-follow way. Why not just do something simple like this? Iterate over the list length and sum that column via the index:

```
List<List<BigDecimal>> matrix = <<your matrix here>>
List<BigDecimal> columnSum= new List<BigDecimal>;
// For each column
for(int i = 0; i < matrix.get(0).size()-1; i++){
      int sum = 0;
      for(List<BigDecimal> row : matrix){
            sum += row.get(i);
      }
      columnSum.add(BigDecimal(sum));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer! I already code solution like yours. But I want to do that using stream api

Comment: @donquih0te Since your question doesn't contain any code, the answerer rightfully assumed that you might find it useful. Please share what have so far regarding this problem.